# Join and count number of values in each subcategory

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say a have a data frame that looks like this:

```
 V290   V311
0   GOOD    TOP QUARTER
1   NK-UNASCERTAIN  MIDDLE HALF
2   AVERAGE TOP QUARTER
3   POOR    NK-UNASCERTAIN
4   POOR    MIDDLE HALF
5   GOOD    MIDDLE HALF
6   POOR    TOP QUARTER
7   AVERAGE MIDDLE HALF
8   POOR    MIDDLE HALF
9   AVERAGE MIDDLE HALF
10  POOR    MIDDLE HALF
11  POOR    MIDDLE HALF
12  AVERAGE MIDDLE HALF
13  AVERAGE TOP QUARTER
```

And i want to group this data by ['V311'] and see how many GOOD or POOR would be in Every ['V311'] Subcategory. 
I want to make something like this:

```
  Top Quarter:GOOD:12
              POOR:30
              Average:15
  Middle half:GOOD:5
              POOR:19
              Average:3
```

And so on...

Answer (score 3):

Use `dict comprehenion` with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and convert to `dict`:

```
d = {k:v.value_counts().to_dict() for k,v in df.groupby('V311')['V290']}
print (d)
{'NK-UNASCERTAIN': {'POOR': 1}, 
'MIDDLE HALF': {'POOR': 4, 'NK-UNASCERTAIN': 1, 'AVERAGE': 3, 'GOOD': 1}, 
'TOP QUARTER': {'POOR': 1, 'AVERAGE': 2, 'GOOD': 1}}
```

For output as `Series`:

```
s = df.groupby('V311')['V290'].value_counts()
print (s)
V311            V290          
MIDDLE HALF     POOR              4
                AVERAGE           3
                GOOD              1
                NK-UNASCERTAIN    1
NK-UNASCERTAIN  POOR              1
TOP QUARTER     AVERAGE           2
                GOOD              1
                POOR              1
Name: V290, dtype: int64
```

EDIT: If need relative frequencies:

```
s = df.groupby('V311')['V290'].value_counts(normalize=True)
print (s)
V311            V290          
MIDDLE HALF     POOR              0.444444
                AVERAGE           0.333333
                GOOD              0.111111
                NK-UNASCERTAIN    0.111111
NK-UNASCERTAIN  POOR              1.000000
TOP QUARTER     AVERAGE           0.500000
                GOOD              0.250000
                POOR              0.250000
Name: V290, dtype: float64
```

EDIT1:

If want all missing categories too:

```
s = df.groupby('V311')['V290'].value_counts()
s = s.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(s.index.levels), fill_value=0)
print (s)
MIDDLE HALF     AVERAGE           3
                GOOD              1
                NK-UNASCERTAIN    1
                POOR              4
NK-UNASCERTAIN  AVERAGE           0
                GOOD              0
                NK-UNASCERTAIN    0
                POOR              1
TOP QUARTER     AVERAGE           2
                GOOD              1
                NK-UNASCERTAIN    0
                POOR              1
Name: V290, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Quick aside. Did you use `read_clipboard` to take the example from the question? I've not used it before, struggling to get the DF to align properly. If so, can you share the correct way to read in the example please? Can't seem to separate on `r"\s+"` or `\t`.

Comment: @roganjosh add some spaces manually between columns and use `sep='\s\s+'`

Answer (score 3):

You can do pivot with unstack i.e

```
df.pivot_table(index='V290',columns='V311',aggfunc='size',fill_value=0).unstack()

V311            V290          
MIDDLE HALF     AVERAGE           3
                GOOD              1
                NK-UNASCERTAIN    1
                POOR              4
NK-UNASCERTAIN  AVERAGE           0
                GOOD              0
                NK-UNASCERTAIN    0
                POOR              1
TOP QUARTER     AVERAGE           2
                GOOD              1
                NK-UNASCERTAIN    0
                POOR              1
dtype: int64
```

Also :

```
df.groupby(['V290','V311']).size().unstack().fillna(0).unstack()
```

If you want the percentage then you can divide by the sum i.e

```
ndf = df.pivot_table(index='V290',columns='V311',aggfunc='size',fill_value=0)
percents = (ndf/ndf.sum()*100).unstack()

V311            V290          
MIDDLE HALF     AVERAGE            33.333333
                GOOD               11.111111
                NK-UNASCERTAIN     11.111111
                POOR               44.444444
NK-UNASCERTAIN  AVERAGE             0.000000
                GOOD                0.000000
                NK-UNASCERTAIN      0.000000
                POOR              100.000000
TOP QUARTER     AVERAGE            33.333333
                GOOD               33.333333
                NK-UNASCERTAIN      0.000000
                POOR               33.333333
dtype: float64
```

Comment: You mean how much does each occupy?

Comment: Thank you a lot! 
In addition to my question, could you be so kind to tell me if it's possible to show this results in % rate. For example: 

         V311            V290          
                MIDDLE HALF     AVERAGE           12%(From overall 'AVERAGE' in Middle Half, Top Quarter and so on.

Comment: thank you a lot, your answer is gorgeous, fully covering my question!

Answer (score 1):

Using only pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
dataframe['V311'] = ['MIDDLE','TOP','MIDDLE','TOP','MIDDLE','TOP','TOP']
print(dataframe['V311'].value_counts())
```

output:

```
TOP       4
MIDDLE    3
Name: V311, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Seriously speaking is this what Op wanted?